# Duplicate request with HTMX on the submit button of the form

Tags: django, htmx

with this code:

```
<button class="button is-success"
type="submit"
hx-get="{% url 'refresh_navbar' %}"
hx-target="#header"
hx-trigger="submit"                                                                              
>Login</button>
```

the post is executed (submited) (the post is done by the hx-post of the form actually)

and this code without the hx-trigger:

```
<button class="button is-success"
type="submit"
hx-get="{% url 'refresh_navbar' %}"
hx-target="#header"                                                                              
>Login</button>
```

executes the get request when i click in the button (but actually i want the get after the submission) and dosent execute the submission.
How can i execute both requests after the form submission event.

I can't put the get in the form, because it already has another target.

```
<form class="form" name="form"        
            hx-post = {{request.path}} 
            hx-trigger="submit"
            hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken":"{{ csrf_token }}"}'
            hx-target="#login-modal"                                                  
            >
```

Thank you guys

the full form is this, it's a modal.
and the #header is in another template

```
<form class="form" name="form"        
            hx-post = {{request.path}} 
            hx-trigger="submit"
            hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken":"{{ csrf_token }}"}'
            hx-target="#login-modal"                                                  
            >
                
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Email</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        {% render_field form.email class="input is-link" placeholder="user@example.com" name="email"%}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        <p class="help is-danger">{{ form.email.errors|first }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Senha</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        {% render_field form.password class="input is-link" placeholder="*********" name="password" %}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        <p class="help is-danger">{{ form.password.errors|first }}</p>
                    {% endif %} 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-success"
                        type="submit"
                        hx-get="{% url 'refresh_navbar' %}"
                        hx-target="#header"
                        hx-trigger="submit"                                                                              
                        >Login</button>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <a class="is-size-8 button-unstyled has-text-link
                               login-modal-tabbable"
                               hx-get="{% url 'register' %}"
                               hx-target="#modal-register"
                               hx-trigger="click once"
                               x-cloak
                               @click.stop.prevent="modalregisteropen = !modalregisteropen">
                  Register new account
                </a>               
                  
            </form>
```

The login view, the form view

```
def user_login(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CustomAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        
        error_messages = form.error_messages
        
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                # User authenticated
                login(request, user)
                
                request.session['success_message'] = "Login bem-sucedido. Bem-vindo!"
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:                
                # Usuário não autenticado - trate conforme necessário
                form.add_error(None, 'Credenciais inválidas. Verifique seu email e senha.')
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form, 'error_messages': error_messages})
```

Comment: Can you include the full form.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response. I've edited the question and included the complete form. Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason I need to make a request to the header is that the navbar is not updating after the login HttpRedirect return. It only updates after I refresh the page. Therefore, I'm attempting to update the header, which includes the navbar.

Comment: Your second comment is a bit confusing. If you say you're redirecting after login, then what is hx-target=#login-modal doing? From your question, I thought by clicking submitting the form you're updating the modal element.

Comment: Can you state clearly what you want to happen AFTER clicking the Login button.

Comment: In the navbar, there is a login button. If the user presses it, a form will appear in a modal. After entering the email and password, they press the login button to submit the authentication. Following the submission, the navbar should be updated, replacing the login button with a logout button. The issue is that the HttpRedirect in the login view to the home doesn't refresh the page; I have to manually refresh the page for the navbar to update.

Comment: The hx-target=#login-modal is a way I use to make the modal appear initially. It's just a div in my base.html. I couldn't find a better way. In base.html, there is this:
{% include 'includes/header.html' %}
            {%block modals%}
            <!-- Login modal -->
            <div id="modal-login"></div>

            <!-- Register modal -->
            <div id="modal-register"></div>
            {%endblock modals%}

Comment: I want the navbar to be updated after the submission. I didn't include all this code and information because I thought it wasn't needed, as the hx-get did the job, but it wasn't happening simultaneously with the submission and when it is submitted, it doesn't trigger the hx-get request.

Comment: Okay. Can you include the view that's handling the redirect?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I included the view that handles the login authentication and the subsequent redirection.

Comment: Good. I'm posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, you don't need the post-submission. You just need to modify your redirect logic.

Import HttpResponse from django.http
Then after you havs logged in the user,

```
def user_login(request:
    .... 
    response = HttpResponse()
    response["Hx-Redirect"] = "/" 
    return response
```

Here, you're just adding the `Hx-Redirect` header to the response object that tells HTMX (on the frontend) to do a page redirect to the specified url.

Comment: MAAAAAANNNN IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THAKS A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. One more thing. When you're making POST requests from a form element, you don't need the `hx-headers` (you already have csrf_token), neither do you need to specify the trigger attribute. So you can remove them and your form will still work the same